# Paint With Image Projection in Texture Paint Mode

Tags: texture-painting

I am comfortable painting in texture paint mode with standard brushes and masks, however how can I use an image as the brush color? Some reason I am not finding a succinct answer here on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using a Brush Texture you are painting with the source texture-color **color-multiplyed** by the Brush color (purple in the case below).

[image]

Just set it to **Full White** (RGB=1,1,1), raise the strenght to 1 and you'll be able to paint the exact colors stored in the texture.

[image]

---

If you need mix the colours of the texture with other textures, you can use the node editor:

[image]